# Can Aggregated classes use each others' function?

Tags: c++, oop

[UML ClassDiagram For Aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6mMx.png)

I want to add a new class name `Bill`, this class generates a bill for a `customer object`. However, I have a function `displayCustomerDetails()` in the class `customer` 
and i want to use that function in class `Bill`. Is that possible with aggregation? (I dont want to do inheritance, just want that particular function in the Bill class)

Comment: A code snippet is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Why would `Bill` have a displayCustomerDetails() function?  It would make sense to have a `displayDetails()` function but why _Customer_ details?  Wouldn't there be some form of _association_ between `Bill` and `Customer`?  such that a `displayDetails()` function in `Bill` would call `bill.customer.displayDetails()`?

Comment: I am new to OOP and we have not yet studied the implementation but UML diagram. So I would like to know that how can i access a certain function of customer i.e displayCustomerDetails() in the Bill class? I am asking for the relation of this method. @JHH

Comment: If `Bill` has access to a `Customer` _instance_ (as it should in this case--it doesn't make sense to have a `Bill` but no `Customer` -- so this is a _dependency_ [aggregation?]) in code you can just call `displayDetails` on the `Customer` instance, assuming the function is `public`, which it should be.  It may help to try to code up the classes for this first.  Trying to learn OOP without code may make trying to understanding what is actually happening difficult.

Comment: @JHH Got You. Thanks :)